# How to integrate track field changes with views

Tags: views

I have enabled [Track Field Changes][1] module and walk through

**admin->system->field** changes here I have check the field for which I want to track....and I created view for that but I don't see anywhere changes I made for that particular field....can anyone know this where I am going wrong?

Comment: Did you do the changes after your installation of Track Field Changes?

Comment: @Huelfe: yes i have done....but what changes exactly you specifying?can you please tell me.

Comment: I mean your changes for your field in your entity. `The module does not use the default Drupal Versioning system. The system will save the time, the user, the value before and after each modification on a field.` This means all changes before installing your module cannot be tracked.

Comment: @Huelfe: so far i have done only installation, and after that walk through admin->system->field changes and check for the field for which i want to track....apart from this i dint do anything....can you please tell me the steps what exactly need to do?it will be great helpful.

Comment: Next step would be: Make a change for your field which you are tracking.

Comment: @Huelfe: yes i edited the content field and saved, once i check in view i could see changed field data [current one]...but no previous data which was saved earlier...where can I see previous field data history.......there is no difference i could see after adding track field changes module...?even i entered log message also i could not find where its getting save..:(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30768/discussion-between-kashish-and-huelfe).